# Creating bean using annotation on-demand

Tags: java, spring

I have a service that can have multiple jobs running simultaneously, all these are long running jobs, thus i have a requirement of statistics showing how these jobs are working, i am using MXbeans for this. As of now i have single bean that encapsulates the stats for all the running jobs, but  this is not easy to read as it has a number of compositeData's in it, so i am thinking of creating individual beans for each job.

Now here is the challenge, as these jobs are added at runtime so the count of them is not fixed, i was planning to create a bean using the @Bean annotation

```
@Bean
public JobsStats jobOne() {
    return new JobsStats ();
}
```

All this logic is working fine for me, where i am stuck is how to create a new bean ONLY when a new jobs is created at runtime, how i can this be achieved?

Comment: What you are trying to do is very specific and the places where I have needed this has always been state aware multithreaded code,ie. You may not reslly need this. Either way You need to annotate the bean for lazy creation and then where you want to use the bean you need a beanfactoryaware object that you can use to create the bean. I'm not near a pc today, so hopefully somebody else and provide a code sample

Comment: I cannot really understand your question. I think you could try to use either prototype or custom scoped beans.

Comment: @Leon - can you please provide me a sample code for this.